# Naming conventions for same concept different names on UI and in DB

Tags: naming-conventions, naming

I have a UI screen which is called "create offer".

Also there is a table in database which is call quote, where this offer will be saved. So ultimately quote <=> offer

In this case what should be the names of my Java classes -> `Offer`, `OfferController`, `OfferService` OR `Quote`, `QuoteContrller`, `QuoteService` etc?

Comment: Sounds like you should come up with the name that describes these both cases if in your case quote is same as offer or vice versa?

Comment: Do you mean that I should use names like QuoteOfferController / OfferQuoteController ?

Comment: Swati Joshi for example yes. Looks good

Comment: Okay but isn't it little confusing?.. Just want to make sure. It seems that I have some table named quote_offer.

Comment: You probably know better what the offer entails, and it is subjective. It could be completely other term, for example PropositionContoller etc.

Comment: Okay understood. Thank you for clarification Maksim!